# Abrir DB berkeley Python

Tags: python, banco-de-dados

Eu recebi um projeto onde tenho um arquivo .db

Tentei abrir-lo com o Sqlitestudio e SQLiteManager, não obtive sucesso.
Fui informado que essa db era uma **database berkeley**.

Gostaria de abrir essa db, se possível, converter ela para uma database normal.
Pesquisei e não achei muito sobre esse tipo de database, explicações ou links sobre essa database são bem vindos!

Mas por favor, me ajudem a abrir e ver o conteúdo, há algum gerenciador?

Comment: Para acessar com o Python, tem esse módulo: https://pypi.org/project/bsddb3

Comment: Obtenho este erro, sabe o que causa ele?
http://prntscr.com/jrtrsq

Comment: Eu recomendo você tentar instalar com o `pip` (que provavelmente vai instalar todas as dependências), mas caso queria instalar manualmente ou caso dê problema novamente, pode baixar o binário o BDB aqui: [Oracle Berkeley DB Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html)